# installation error while run setup

Tags: magento2

I have take a clone from bitbucket ,did composer update and create a database and thn while running setup , its stop on 50% and throgh 
Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Invalid entity_type specified: customer error

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: not yet ! just take backup from another one